# Total current in two circuits - two methods

Tags: current, current-source

I have two norton's theorem questions and I am confused about the two solutions.
In the first one below, the current can be found by simply subtracting one current from another. (I believe this is correct)
\$I_N\$ = current through \$R_L\$ in the first circuit
\$R_L = 21 \Omega\$
[image: circuit 1]

But in the second circuit, you have to use the current divider rule. 
[image: circuit 2]

Am I missing something completely obvious? why is the first one so simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I missing something completely obvious? why is the first one so
>   simple?

I can't see what you are calculating in (1) - what is \$I_N\$? For (2) you just calculate the impedance seen by the current source: -

4 ohms in parallel with 4 ohms (makes 2 ohms) and these are in series with a 2 ohm resistor making 4 ohms and, this is in parallel with a 6 ohms resistor making a total load of 2.4 ohms.

This produces a voltage at the current generator of 19.2 volts. This causes a current to flow through the 2 ohm resistor of 4.8 A (remember the 2 ohms is in series with two paralleled 4 ohms).

For each 4 ohm load this current is shared meaning \$I_N\$ is 2.4 A.

Comment: Sorry, I have made an edit now that hopefully makes it more clear.

Comment: @Gurn64 but you cannot calculate this current because RL isn't known so, in conclusion, the 2nd circuit is infinitely easier to solve!!!

Comment: Again, my apologies for leaving out information, I'm new to this! Hopefully it is corrected now?

Comment: OK, so same technique, find the total effective load seen by the current generators - it's a little easier because all three resistors are in ||. Rtotal = 3.652 ohms. Current is 5 - 10/12 = 4.16667 A and this produces a voltage that is approx 15.22 volts - this is across RL therefore its current is 0.725 amps

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, since \$I_N\$ is obtained by short-cicuiting the terminals, you shirt-circuit all resistors, so you effectively only have the two current sources. In the other example, if you short-circuit the terminals all resistors remain 'active' (in the sense that current flows through them). So your first example is a very special case because it already is almost a Norton equivalent cicuit.

Comment: The op is now saying that RL is not a short circuit.

Comment: @Andyaka: Hmmm, but for obtaining I_N (the Norton current), we have to short-circuit the output terminals. Where are they then?